# New UIView not loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a TabController View setup and I am attempting to load a new view in the current tab. This view would be loaded depending on a selection from a UIAlertView.

As such I have this code attempting to do so:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    // Yes Button
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {

        NSLog(@"%@ Pressed", [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:0]);

        user = [[UserInfo alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserInfo"  bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:user animated:YES];

        [user release];
    }
    // Don't show again Button
    if (buttonIndex == 1) { 
        NSLog(@"%@ Pressed", [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:1]);
    }

    // No Button
    if (buttonIndex == 2) {
        NSLog(@"%@ Pressed", [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:2]);
    }
}
```

The Yes block prints out to the console, however the new view does not load. User is an instance of UserInfo, which in turn is a subclass of UIViewController. The Nib UserInfo is created and is part of the project.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines are unnecessary:

```
[user.view setHidden:NO];
[self.navigationController setView:user.view];
```

But this one is:

```
[user release];
```

---

How are you setting up your tab bar controller?  Have you placed this view inside of a UINavigationController then added that navigation controller to the TabBarController?

Please review the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningViewControllers/CombiningViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH104-SW1) (specifically the Combined ViewController Interfaces section) and verify you are nesting these views correctly.

Comment: Ah yes, while that is true (lapse in memory, forgot to uncomment the release and comment out the other two lines) this does not fix the issue at hand.

Comment: @BOMEz I have updated my answer, I am concerned you don't actually have a navigationcontroller which would explain this behavior.

Comment: Your suggestion itself didn't fix my problem but it got me thinking down the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Is user a global variable? I usually see something like
    UserInfo *user = [[UserInfo alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserInfo"  bundle:nil];

as the pattern. Since the navigation controller is really going to be the main owner of the view

Comment: Yes it is a global variable. in the .h file I have _UserInfo *user_ along with @property(nonatomic,retain) _UserInfo *user;_ In the .m file _user) is synthesized.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to check your MainWindow.xib (the one that is housing the tab controller) and make sure that for the TabBar controller that the tab you want is set as a UINavigationController instead of a ViewController. In IB click on the Tab Bar Controller and look at its Attributes window to see what type of controller each tab is set for.